# Physics2D.Raycast is returning null randomly

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a board with cells, some are normal and some are walls. I would like to set a line between two points and know if it's colliding with a wall cell.

Here is my code:

```
private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    RaycastHit2D raycast = Physics2D.Raycast(from, to, Vector2.Distance(from, to), layerMask);
    if (raycast.collider == null) { Gizmos.color = Color.green; Gizmos.DrawLine(from, to); }
    else { Gizmos.color = Color.red; Gizmos.DrawLine(from, to); }
}
```

It works 80% of the time. At certain points in the map it's not working at all.

Example when it's OK

[image: Example when it's OK]

In this case it's ok, but if I go down my bottom right point for about 0.2, it's not working anymore.

Example when it's not OK

[image: Example when it's not OK]

My line pass green like there are no wall at all.

I have set BoxCollider2D and my Layer on wall cell.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument in [Physics2D.Raycast()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) is the "direction," not the end of the ray (unlike [Gizmos.DrawLine()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.DrawLine.html), which you *are* calling properly because it *does* use a start and end as arguments).  You want something like this:

```
Vector2 direction = to - from;
Physics2D.Raycast(from, direction.normalized, direction.magnitude, layerMask);
```

You've also got some duplicated code in your proceeding `if` statement that could be cleaned up:

```
Gizmos.Color = (raycast.collider == null) ? Color.green : Color.red;
Gizmos.DrawLine(from, to);
```